# How to add a key-chord escape in Evil for input in other languages?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, input-method, key-chord-mode

*How do I get key-chords to work with `evil` and alternate input-methods?*

I enabled Korean input by `M-x set-input-method` and chose `korean-hangul`, which I found from following the first few instructions from [this Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WritingKorean).

I am using `evil-mode`, which I really enjoy, but my custom "smash escape" function does not work. The function allows me to exit `insert` state by quickly pressing `jk` or `kj`. Here are the functions:

```
;; Set 'kj' to exit insert mode
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "k" #'cofi/maybe-exit-kj)
(evil-define-command cofi/maybe-exit-kj ()
  :repeat change
  (interactive)
  (let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (insert "k")
    (let ((evt (read-event (format "Insert %c to exit insert state" ?j)
               nil 0.5)))
      (cond
       ((null evt) (message ""))
       ((and (integerp evt) (char-equal evt ?j))
    (delete-char -1)
    (set-buffer-modified-p modified)
    (push 'escape unread-command-events))
       (t (setq unread-command-events (append unread-command-events
                          (list evt))))))))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map "j" #'cofi/maybe-exit-jk)
(evil-define-command cofi/maybe-exit-jk ()
  :repeat change
  (interactive)
  (let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (insert "j")
    (let ((evt (read-event (format "Insert %c to exit insert state" ?k)
               nil 0.5)))
      (cond
       ((null evt) (message ""))
       ((and (integerp evt) (char-equal evt ?k))
    (delete-char -1)
    (set-buffer-modified-p modified)
    (push 'escape unread-command-events))
       (t (setq unread-command-events (append unread-command-events
                          (list evt))))))))
```

My attempt was to substitute `j` and `k` with the corresponding Korean characters. Here is my attempt at re-implementing the `kj` smash escape, where the character `ㅏ` is bound to `k` and the character `ㅓ` is bound to `j`:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "ㅏ" #'cofi/maybe-exit-ㅏㅓ)
;; Set 'ㅏㅓ' to exit insert mode
(evil-define-command cofi/maybe-exit-ㅏㅓ ()
  :repeat change
  (interactive)
  (let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (insert "ㅏ")
    (let ((evt (read-event (format "Insert %c to exit insert state" ?ㅓ)
               nil 0.5)))
      (cond
       ((null evt) (message ""))
       ((and (integerp evt) (char-equal evt ?ㅓ))
    (delete-char -1)
    (set-buffer-modified-p modified)
    (push 'escape unread-command-events))
       (t (setq unread-command-events (append unread-command-events
                          (list evt))))))))
```

All I did was substitute `j` and `k` with `ㅓ` and `ㅏ`, respectively. Unfortunately, it does not work. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I presume you're aware of [`key-chord`](http://www.emacswiki.org/KeyChord) (see also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150003/binding-the-escape-key-to-a-keychord-for-evil-mode)).  I've never used it, and have hazy memories that it [doesn't always interact well with `evil`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/28/execute-commands-ninja-style-with-key-chord-mode/).

This answer is 95% of the way there.  The last snag looks like it's in the actual binding of the key, but I don't know how to fix it because I don't know how Korean input methods work.

Here's a version using *Arabic* (helpful, right?) that *does* work; I've left comments on which lines you need to change to switch it over to Korean:

```
(evil-define-command cofi/maybe-exit-kj ()
  :repeat change
  (interactive)
  (let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (self-insert-command 1)
    (let ((evt (read-event (format "Insert %c to exit insert state"
                                   (if (equal current-input-method
                                              "arabic") ; "korean-hangul"
                                       ?ؤ               ; ?ㅓ
                                     ?j))
                           nil 0.5)))
      (cond
       ((null evt) (message ""))
       ((and (integerp evt) (memq evt '(?j ?ؤ))) ; '(?j ?ㅓ)
        (delete-char -1)
        (set-buffer-modified-p modified)
        (push 'escape unread-command-events))
       (t
        (setq unread-command-events (append unread-command-events
                                            (list evt))))))))
```

Now: it turns out that you also need to bind the key in the relevant alphabet to this function as well (with `ر` standing in for the `k`):

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "ر" #'cofi/maybe-exit-kj) ; "ㅏ"
```

It looks like the problem is with the `define-key` part:

```
(defun test-my-key ()
  (interactive)
  (self-insert-command 1)
  (message "This key works!")
  (sit-for 2))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map "a" #'test-my-key)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "ㅏ" #'test-my-key)
```

Now, when entering `a`, it self-inserts an `a` into the buffer, but you don't get anything when entering `ㅏ` -- I presume because Emacs is waiting for you to complete the character with another key?  At any rate, you'll know better how to deal with Korean input methods, so will be able to adjust the function as needed.