# Using 'jk' to exit insert mode with key-chord or anything else

Tags: evil

I'm trying to transfer over from vim to Emacs. I'm using `evil` to emulate vim modal editing. In vim, I've remapped `jk` to get me out of insert mode and back into normal mode using `inoremap jk <esc>`. At the moment, I'm using

```
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)
(key-chord-define evil-replace-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)
```

to do this in Emacs.

However, when I'm in insert mode and want to type, say, `jump`, I end up with just `mp`, and `j u is undefined` appears under the mode bar.

Is there any way to fix this behaviour? Preferably, the solution would even allow me to type `jk` by typing `j`, waiting, and then typing `k` (like in vim).

---

**UPDATE** 

To clarify, I was only using `key-chord` as a temporary solution to get me  into normal mode; I am very willing to accept any solution that fixes the *problem*, regardless of whether it involves `key-chord`.

Comment: This shouldn't happen in the first place with key-chord.

Comment: `(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)` let's you escape from insert mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I cannot reproduce the condition as reported above.  It would be helpful if you could share a minimal configuration that can reproduce this error of yours.

An alternative way of solving this is writing a command bound to the initial key of the escape sequence that waits with a timeout for another event to occur.  If this event happens in a timely manner and matches the final key of the escape sequence, execute the command to exit insert state.  If the timeout is met, but the final key is wrong, insert the initial key and the different one.  If the timeout is missed, insert the first key.

```
(defun my-jk ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((initial-key ?j)
         (final-key ?k)
         (timeout 0.5)
         (event (read-event nil nil timeout)))
    (if event
        ;; timeout met
        (if (and (characterp event) (= event final-key))
            (evil-normal-state)
          (insert initial-key)
          (push event unread-command-events))
      ;; timeout exceeded
      (insert initial-key))))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "j") 'my-jk)
```

Another implementation of the above with slightly different semantics can be found in [cofi's config](https://github.com/cofi/dotfiles/blob/a000343ad9268786d459c776fbcf267036999422/emacs.d/config/cofi-evil.el#L81-L95).

Comment: The file you like to is far from trivial. Can you add a line reference so we can quickly jump to the section you mention?

Answer (score 4):

You have, in effect, defined `j` as a prefix key, which means that any key you press after it is looked up in the keymap associated with `j`.  Since `u` is undefined after `j` you get the behavior you see.

A key cannot be bound to two different commands.  In particular, it cannot be bound to both `self-insert-command` (or equivalent), which inserts a character, and bound to a keymap (acts as a prefix key).

What you can do instead is to bind `j` to a command that reads a character and does something different depending on what that character is: If it is `k` then do `evil-normal-state`.  If it is any other character than `k` then it inserts that character.

Something like this (but you would bind the key in some Evil mode, no doubt, not globally):

```el
(defun my-j ()
  "Read a char.  If `k' then invoke `evil-normal-state'.  Else insert it."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ch  (read-char-exclusive)))
    (if (eq ?k ch)
        (message "Invoke EVIL-NORMAL-STATE HERE") ;; (evil-normal-state)
      (insert "j" (string ch)))))

(global-set-key "j" 'my-j)
```

Comment: This can be done significantly better by taking a timeout into account, see [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3825/how-to-add-a-key-chord-escape-in-evil-for-input-in-other-languages) for a code example.

Comment: Also, the first part of the explanation does not apply as this is not regular `define-key`, but `key-chord-define`...

Comment: @wasamasa; could you put this into an answer?

Comment: Neither of these answer the question as is, so I won't until it changes to reflect that you're no longer interested in using key-chord to escape from Evil's insert state.

Comment: @wasamasa; I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)` let's you escape from insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am using General.el package for this, with following config.

```
(use-package general
  :config
  (general-evil-setup)
  ;; Exit insert state / mode using jk keybind using general.el package
   (general-imap "j"
    (general-key-dispatch 'self-insert-command
   :timeout 0.25
   "k" 'evil-normal-state))
```

GL